# 1.9 - Redirect customer group to CMS page

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-group

I am trying to redirect a specific customer group to a single CMS page. Not just after logging in, but whenever they try to go to any page, it will just redirect them to the CMS page.

The only file I figured I could add code is in `header.phtml`.

```
$customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();

    if($customerGroupId == 5){

            $redirect_url = Mage::getUrl('uhoh');
         Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirect_url)->sendResponse();
    }
```

This is what I currently have. It's purpose works, but it's not exactly what I want. The purpose is for a "blocked" customer group. This code sends the user into an endless redirect, but I want to have information displayed on the CMS page, which means no page is useless despite actually blocking the group from using the site.

Is there an issue with the code? Or would it be easier and more effective to create a module for this?

Comment: To stop the infinite loop you might be able to add another condition to your if statement not to fire the redirect if current url == target url.  You can get current url using `$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, after thinking about it, this made complete sense. I tried doing `if(!$currentUrl == $url) { //redirect}` but it failed. However, `if($currentUrl == $url) {} else { // redirect }` worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, the first example would work like this `if($currentUrl != $url) { //redirect}` but glad you got it to work!

Comment: Yeah, I realized I just messed up the operator location. Or `!($currentUrl == $url)` could have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the infinite loop from happening, add a 2nd condition to your IF statement checking the current URL:

```
$customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
$redirect_url = Mage::getUrl('uhoh');

    if($customerGroupId == 5 && $currentUrl !== $redirect_url ){  
         Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirect_url)->sendResponse();
    }
```